# What does the false in addEventListener('click', stopEvent, false) mean?

Tags: javascript

What does the third argument 'false' represent in the last line of the bellow code?

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent'),
child  = document.getElementById('child'),
op     = document.getElementById('op'),
op2    = document.getElementById('op2');

parent.addEventListener('click', function () {
  op.innerHTML += '<p>click registered</p>';
}, false);

function stopEvent (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  op2.innerHTML += '<p>propagation stopped</p>';
}

child.addEventListener('click', stopEvent, false);
```

Comment: Maybe look at the docs? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: The opposite of event bubbling if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yes, the documentation says: If not specified, useCapture defaults to false. But why?

Comment: You mean, why is it set to `false` in the code even though it already defaults to `false`? If it defaults to `false`, then `child.addEventListener('click', stopEvent);` would be equivalent. A programmer may choose to make the parameter explicit for clarity.

Comment: No, the documentation says *"If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture."* and *"See [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) for a detailed explanation."*

Comment: its even the first hit at google [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: Thank you all for fast referencing to the documentation. But I was more after 'in English' explanation. As someone smart once said: If you cannot explain the subject to 6 years old, you don't understand the subject yourself.

Answer (score 2):

if it is true it would be considered at the beginning of the all other added function (it is called `captured`), if not it would be just simply add to the end of list (called `bubbled`), let's say you have:

```
parent.addEventListener('click', function () { console.log("nocapture1"); }, false);
parent.addEventListener('click', function () { console.log("usecapture1"); }, true);
parent.addEventListener('click', function () { console.log("nocapture2"); }, false);
parent.addEventListener('click', function () { console.log("usecapture2"); }, false);
```

then once it is clicked, you would have them with this order in the console:

```
usecapture1
usecapture2
nocapture1
nocapture2
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was after. For javascript novice going through documentation is not always helpful. The real examples are bless.

Answer (score 1):

It specifies whether or not you want to capture the event.  In this case, it isn't necessary because it defaults to `false` anyway.  See the [MDN documentation for `element.addEventListener`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html) for more information.